# java sound byte array conversions

Tags: java, audio

i am developing a sound application.

`javax.sound.sampled.TargetDataLine` reads from the input channel in 16 bit format

i have a 3rd party app that reads in 32 bit to a byteBuffer

how can i convert/interpert the 32 bit bytebuffer to a 16 bit byte array?

Answer (score 0):

it can be smt like (without check, only idea):

```
//32 -> 16
for(int i = 0; i < newarray.length; i += 2){
    newarray[i] = oldarray[i/2] & ~0 << 16;
    newarray[i+1] = oldarray[i/2] & ~0 >> 16;
}
```